# solr multiple server dataimport handler throws exception - Properties is not writable

Tags: solr, solr4

Thanks in advanced,

am tried to setup two solr servers in tomcat7 (ubuntu). Below here is the steps i followed,

1. create to context file inside tomcat7 localhost directory

   - `/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr.xml`
   - `/tomcat7/Catalina/localhost/solr-cc.xml`
2. create two seperate solr instances

   - `/etc/solr-4.6.a/solr.war` & index directories
   - `/etc/solr-4.6.b/solr.war` & index directories

Server started fine and am able to see both solr admin pages, but when i tried to index data, am using dataimport handler (put separate configuration entries in two servers), first instance `/solr` is running fine, but the second one `/solr-cc` throws below exception:

```
Full Import failed:
org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Properties is not writable. Delta imports are supported by data config but will not work. Processing Document # 1
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.checkWritablePersistFile(DataImporter.java:426)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:410)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:476)
at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter$1.run(DataImporter.java:457)
```

I tried more then an hour to fix but failed, I gave all the file permission as 777 to index and solr config files directories.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: I got bitten by this, turned out to be disk space... My `df -h` showed 0 bytes available in my disk!

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure your dataimport.properties file is writable by tomcat user(I assume tomcat7), you could change the owner on all the files from conf folder to tomcat.

Let me know if it worked.

Comment: Thanks @geryjuhasz!!

My dataimport.properties file is readable. I have given 777 permission for that file. 

"you could change the owner on all the files from conf folder to tomcat" -- am not able to follow you could you please berif me in detail. 

Thanks again for you help!!